# WebSocket Server: HttpListener vs WCFWebSocket

Tags: c#, wcf, websocket, httplistener

I have to implement a WebSocketsServer to deal with several WebSockets Clients communications and while searching I've found a lot of ways to implement this... now I'm a little confused which is the best approach.

What are the pros and cons of using a server that uses HttpListener vs WCFWebSocket?

Should I use Microsoft.ServiceModel.WebSockets wrapper or System.Net.WebSockets?

Windows8/Windows Server 2012 and IIS8 are requisites that I can support.